# Listen to Firebase DB updates from server

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a server to perform certain actions when a mobile app updates an entry in a Firebase database. The intended flow is:

1. App updates Firebase database
2. Server detects change, performs action with data

Currently I'm using the Firebase REST API to periodically query Firebase and get the proper table. Is there a better way to do this?

I've read the documentation for [Firebase asynchronous listeners](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html), but there's no page that has to be loaded, the extent of the functionality is running something on the server based on the data updated.

Comment: Did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start ?

Comment: ...I didn't. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pooling, you can get updates on changes from cloud functions.
On every change the cloud function will trigger an HTTP request to your server endpoint.
See examples here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/minimal-webhook